# How do I remove programs from the "Open with" menu in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I looked at

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.extension\OpenWithList
```

and only the `a` key is there, not the six programs in the menu for a file with the `.mp4` extension. How can I remove them? Thank you!

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations holds these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check here HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.mp4\OpenWithProgids

Comment: That works, but how do I tell which 'metro' apps are which?

Comment: Nevermind, I just renamed them and saw what disappeared from the menu. Thanks!